# Mysql Trigger to INSERT a record or UPDATE the count if it already exists?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables 
1st table word_cloud (auto inc), predefined_text, content_id .
2nd table word_cloud_count (auto inc),predefined_text,content_id,count .
I am calling a trigger when data is inserted into word_cloud, which basically groups the word, calculates the count and inserts it into word_cloud_count

word_cloud table consists of

```
id | predefined_text | content_id
---------------------------------
 1 | ABC             | 1
 2 | ABC             | 1
 3 | ABC             | 1
 4 | XYZ             | 2
 5 | XYZ             | 2
 6 | XYZ             | 2
 7 | XYZ             | 1
 8 | ABC             | 2
 9 | ABC             | 2
10 | ABC             | 2
```

word_cloud_count consists of

```
id | predefined_text | content_id | count
-----------------------------------------------
 1 | ABC             | 1          |  3
 2 | XYZ             | 2          |  3
 3 | ABC             | 2          |  3
 4 | XYZ             | 1          |  1
 5 | ABC             | 1          |  3
 6 | XYZ             | 2          |  3
 7 | ABC             | 2          |  3
 8 | XYZ             | 1          |  1
```

In the above table word_cloud_count row number 5,6,7,8 are duplicate data,

**Trigger Function**

```
CREATE TRIGGER word_cloud_count_insert after insert on word_cloud
    INSERT INTO word_cloud_count (Word,content_id ,count )
    SELECT predefined_text,content_id, count(*)
    FROM word_cloud
    group by predefined_text,content_id
```

Everything works fine and the values are being inserted in the word_cloud_count table

However my problem is every time the data is inserted into word_cloud the trigger is called and duplicate values are being stored into word_cloud_count

How do i avoid this , and update only the counter if a new record is inserted in word_cloud

Any suggestions would be of great Help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same table? take a look:

Creating a table with all those columns:

```
create table word_cloud
(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    predefined_text varchar(200),
    content_id int,
    `count` int default 1, 
    unique (predefined_text,content_id)  -- important
);
```

When you run an insert statement add the extra sentence `on duplicate`:

```
INSERT INTO word_cloud (predefined_text,content_id) VALUES ('XYZ',1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;

INSERT INTO word_cloud (predefined_text,content_id) VALUES ('ABC',1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;

INSERT INTO word_cloud (predefined_text,content_id) VALUES ('XYZ',2)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;
```

After execute randomly that inserts sometimes you will get:

```
mysql> select * from word_cloud;
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+
| id | predefined_text | content_id | count |
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+
|  1 | XYZ             |          1 |     2 |
|  3 | ABC             |          1 |     7 |
| 10 | XYZ             |          2 |     1 |       
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you ,this helped me get a different approach